# Python: what is the simplest way to convert utf8 string to &#0000;

Tags: python, html, utf-8, string-conversion

I have a utf8 string with non-ASCII chars. I need to put it to html file in the ampersand-hash-digits-semicolon form. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What is being converted, the UTF-8 bytes or the Unicode codepoint they encode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.encode` method with `'xmlcharrefreplace'` passed as `errors` parameter:

```
In [1]: help(unicode.encode)
Help on method_descriptor:

encode(...)
    S.encode([encoding[,errors]]) -> string or unicode

    Encodes S using the codec registered for encoding. encoding defaults
    to the default encoding. errors may be given to set a different error
    handling scheme. Default is 'strict' meaning that encoding errors raise
    a UnicodeEncodeError. Other possible values are 'ignore', 'replace' and
    'xmlcharrefreplace' as well as any other name registered with
    codecs.register_error that can handle UnicodeEncodeErrors.
```

---

```
In [2]: ustr = u'\xa9 \u20ac'

In [3]: print ustr
© €

In [4]: print ustr.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
&#169; &#8364;
```

Comment: @gipi - yes. added an example.